# Codeigniter FacebookSDK, base_facebook.php library

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

Hello there I am listing now the base_facebook.php file and can't see in there a function which gives back the username of the user. There is only a function getUser() which returns the user ID. Can you navigate me about the way how to take the username of a user with this FB SDK in codeigniter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make an API call to get the user details:

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
var_dump($me);
```

**Although, the username is not included anymore since v2.0, for privacy reasons.**

This is for the old PHP SDK btw, but i assume that is what you are using. The new one works completely different and needs PHP 5.4+. Here´s a tutorial, just in case: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

Comment: I see that this function returns an associative array. I edited it a little:
         
              $username = $this->facebook->api('/me');
              var_dump($username[name]);

Comment: calling it $username would be completely wrong, it´s a user object with some variables (id, name, ...), not just a username. and as i said, the username is not even included anymore ;) - meaning, you can´t get the username in v.2.0+ apps.

Comment: also, it would be like this: var_dump($username['name']);